# css: height: 100vh - 120px = 98.75vh?

Tags: css, sass

I came across this issue when I forgot to put `calc` in my scss, so the css was like

```
div{height:100vh - 120px}
```

and in front end, this turns out to be

```
div{height:98.75vh}
```

I am just curious where this 98.75 comes from. How did the browser interpret `100vh - 120px`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes I just confirmed it.

Comment: so we need more detail about the compiler used. Here you get an error: https://www.sassmeister.com/ and trying it as a regular CSS you get an invalid property

Comment: [www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/](https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/)

Comment: No spec compliant compiler will allow this, the unnamed tool in the above link is obviously buggy.

Comment: Well it makes sense if your viewport height is 9600px...

Answer (score -1):

In general, it means that 120px is 1,25% of your viewport height.
IMO `div{height:100vh - 120px}` did not throw an error because of SCSS handled it and transformed it into CSS but I'm not 100% sure.